# How To Improve Conditional Logic With Java 8

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm in the process of learning Java 8 and I wanted to know if there was a clean way to re-write the below code more efficiently in Java 8:

```
public static Map<String, Character> parseOrg(String org) {
    Map<String, Character> map = new HashMap<String, Character>();
    if (org != null && !org.isEmpty()) {
        String modifiedString = trimOrg(org); //private method to substring
        if (modifiedString.length() == 4) {
            populateMap(modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-1), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-2), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-3), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-4));
        } else if (modifiedString.length == 3) {
            populateMap(modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-1), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-2), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-3), null);
        } else if (modifiedString.length == 2) {
            populateMap(modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-1), modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-2), null, null);
        } else if (modifiedString.length == 1) {
            populateMap(modifiedString.charAt(modifiedString.length()-1), null, null, null);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.error("Null org provided");
    }
    return map;
}

private static void populateMap(Map<String, Character> map, Character pos0, Character pos1, Character pos2, Character pos3) {
    map.put("Position 3", pos3);
    map.put("Position 2", pos2);
    map.put("Position 1", pos1);
    map.put("Position 0", pos0);
}
```

Comment: Other than converting it to a `switch`, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: What's the map for? You are just creating it and returning it empty.

Comment: Updated the comments to add some more clarity. The doX private method is used to populate the map.

Comment: So they're all calling the same method? Why all the repetition then?

Comment: The edits to this question confuse me.  After changing all the method calls to doX() this becomes pretty obvious!

Comment: Sorry, was trying to avoid re-writing all the code since I can't copy + paste. The edits should now make the intent of the code a little more clear.

Comment: `int l = modifiedString.length(); 
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> map.put("Position " + i, i >= l? null: modifiedString.charAt(l - i - 1)));`

Comment: @Holger Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Saved me a ton of lines of code. Wish you could put that as the answer so I could give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
Runnable r = Arrays.asList(() -> {}, YourClass::doD, YourClass::doC, YourClass::doB, YourClass::doA, () -> {})
    .get(Math.min(Math.max(0, org.length()), 4));
r.run();
```

But honestly, it's not worth it. Just use a switch.

Comment: They're static methods.

Comment: What's the second `get()` about?

Comment: You can skip the first element and decrement length.

Comment: @shmosel you can, but it's convenient to handle out-of-range indices. See update.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is strange because it appears to call the same `doX()` method every time. If that is really what you want, you can have a simple if-statement and supply it a range:

```
if(modifiedString.length() >= 1 && modifiedString.length() <= 4) {
    doX();
}
```

If indeed you meant that they are different methods and do different things depending on the `modifiedString.length` value, you can use a switch-statement, as suggested by others:

```
switch (modifiedString.length()) {
    case 1:
        doA();
        break;
    case 2:
        doB();
        break;
    case 3:
        doC();
        break;
    case 4:
        doD();
        break;
    default:
        //if no case match
}
```